# My form doesn't submit image file to controller store function, What is the problem

Tags: laravel

I want to send an image file to the controller store method, but the input file sends a temp file what is the problem, anyone can help me?

My Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('books.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                        @csrf
                        @method('POST')
                       
                        <input type="file"  name="cover_image" value="{{old('cover')}}">
                    <input type="submit" class="" value="send">
                    </form>
```

when I return:

```
return $request->cover_image;
```

the result is :

```
C:\xampp\tmp\phpF61B.tmp
```

Comment: Welcome to SO...  Pls include the code you are attempting in the question

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a section [File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-uploads), didn't that help?

Comment: Pls post/include the code of your controller method

Comment: I just want to return the submitted file in cocntroller like this return $request->cover_image; but the result is : C:\xampp\tmp\phpF61B.tmp;

Comment: If you want to get name of uploaded file try this `$request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();`

Comment: The main problem is that the file is not sending to the controller

Comment: File seems to be uploaded properly as it is showing a tmp path. In your controller you can try $file = $request->file('cover_image'); dd($file->getClientOriginalName); to check for yourself

Comment: ErrorException
fopen(E:\wels_nangarhar\storage\app\public/images/book/cover_image/2020-12-11 12:31:13-9780838418079-us.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: my controller store function code

Comment: if($request->hasfile('cover_image')) {
            $filenameWithExt=$request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $imageName=pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);;
            $extension=$request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $imageNameToStore=$imageName.'_'.now().'.'.$extension;
            $path=$request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/images/book/cover_image/', $imageNameToStore);
        }
        else {
            $imageNameToStore='noimage.jpg';
        }